# libcurl: send GET requests after timeout limit is reached

Tags: c++, networking, https, libcurl, polling

**Problem:**

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

When a target URL updates its content, recently `libcurl` has had unexpected polling delays / timeouts anywhere between 2 and 20+ seconds between sending a `GET` request to the target URL and receiving any response.

I have no idea what has been causing this behaviour, and have detailed all of the `strace` reports, `tshark` results, entire `libcurl C++` program, attempts to diagnose, and other terminal outputs at the following SO question, but have had no luck in diagnosing this for about four months:

[libcurl: abnormal GET response delays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69993012/libcurl-abnormal-get-response-delays)

There seems to be something between the client server and remote server that is stopping packets from being returned, but only when the page changes its content. During this polling delay / timeout, no other requests can be sent - therefore any new data uploaded on the remote server cannot be retrieved quickly.

This issue did not exist before mid-July 2021. Given that after four months this problem still hasn't been solved, I want to attempt a workaround that will still send requests to the target when this polling delay presents itself. I won't understand what caused the polling timeouts, but hopefully I will be able to retrieve the data without delays like the program used to do.

Target URL: https://ir.eia.gov/wpsr/table4.csv

**Summary questions:**

**Q1.** Is there a `timeout` option with `libcurl` that, when exceeded, the program does not exit but instead sends another `GET` request to the target URL?

**Q2.** Since this problem only arises when the target URL makes a scheduled content update, could there be a chance the target URL changes its `IP address` and thus there is some delay caused by a `DNS resolution` server in between the client and remote side on the return leg? I am going to attempt to use a tool like `pingPlotter` to see if there is a delay at some specific `IP address` between the outbound `GET` request and the response.

Before any scheduled page content changes, the `latency` between the outbound `GET` request and the response is `<100 ms`.

Comment: Alternative explanation: the remote side either turns on its firewall while updating the content or is hammered by other clients around that time and unable to serve you. Have you considered contacting the owners of the site?

Comment: As for Q2: it is highly irregular to change IP addresses whenever you update content. Even so, the "old" IP should not simply stop responding.

Comment: @Botje I have contacted the owner of the site, my case is an isolated incident. They employ cyber security measures such as snort, but my IP has not been blacklisted. High web traffic is not a concern either, and the remote side is provided via CDN.

Comment: To add to the above, I have also tried off of different IP addresses in different data centre locations (i.e. London, New York), as well as using `wget` and `curl` instead of `libcurl`. The same behaviour occurs each time.

Comment: "_This issue did not exist before mid-July 2021_" - What happened around that time? Did you install a new version of `libcurl` or change _anything_ on your side?

Comment: No, absolutely no changes were made to the libcurl program and no new version of libcurl was installed. The program literally changed its behaviour overnight... maybe there was some automatic kernel update that may have somehow impacted the performance of libcurl on my local machine, although I believe I checked this at the time and saw no new updates

Comment: In addition to the above, I believe that this behaviour occurs on other URLs also after running a test a couple of days ago, and not just the target URL listed. I have made an edit to the question showing my OS as well.

Comment: And you get the same problem even when you run the command line `curl` command?

Comment: Yep, I observe the exact same problem when using the `curl` command and `wget`.

Comment: Hmm... Do you have some proxy between you and the target server? I can connect and download the page with a `libcurl` program in `0.160s`. If you add some random data to the url with every request, like `https://ir.eia.gov/wpsr/table4.csv?foo=1` (and step to `2` for the next request and so on), do you same see the same behavior? Also, if you use `wget` to download the document, do you see the same issue?

Comment: I ran `echo $http_proxy` which returned nothing - I don't think there is any proxy between myself and the remote side. I have also ran the program by appending random data at the end of the URL to determine if this was a caching issue, and the problem persisted. Also the problem persists with `wget` i.e. there is no response from the download request until after 2-20 seconds (when the scheduled page update is made). I've seen other users receiving this updated data in the usual 100-200ms range.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on this one? I’m wondering if it’s a DNS server causing the issue…